# PNG Image transparency in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame, python-imaging-library

I have been trying to display a .PNG image with transparent portions in tkinter. But I am running into a problem. While displaying the image, it tends to lose its transparency. Is there any way to solve this issue?
I am new to tkinter but proficient in pygame and I have already applied this idea in pygame and it seems to work.
Here is the code I have written so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkfont
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Kiara")
root.geometry("706x462")

#Images
home_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:/Kiara Project/Screens/home_button.png"))
note_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:/Kiara Project/Screens/note_button.png"))
about_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:/Kiara Project/Screens/about_button.png"))
menu_home_activated_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:/Kiara Project/Screens/menu_home_activated.png"))

#Buttons
home_button = Button(root, image=home_button_image, bd=0)
note_button = Button(root, image=note_button_image, bd=0)
about_button = Button(root, image=about_button_image, bd=0)

#Screens
menu_home_activated = Label(root, image=menu_home_activated_image, bd=0)

menu_home_activated.place(x=0, y=0)
note_button.place(x=300, y=50)

root.update()

root.mainloop()
```

And here is the output:
[image]

The menu_home_activated.png is of the same size as the tkinter window and is transparent except for the parts which are visible in the output.
As you can see, the note_button is not displayed even though it is placed in the transparent section.
I am using Python 3.8.3 if it helps.

Comment: tkinter `Label` and `Button` do not support transparent image.  Only `Canvas.create_image()` does.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to use it in my case?

Comment: I don't know why the `note_button` is not shown because it is placed after the label, i.e. it should be shown on top of the label.

Comment: I have added the two .png files if you want to try it out!!

Comment: It is not even working with Canvas.create_image(). I have tried that option also!!

Comment: Neither, the `note_button.png` nor `home_button.png` are transparent.

Comment: There must have have been some problem while uploading. I can guarantee you that it is indeed transparent as I have designed it myself in Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: You can't stack widgets, can't recall the reference, even [The Tkinter Place Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) claims: ***...place two widgets on top of each other***: See a [working solution](https://repl.it/repls/WatchfulShockedCases#main.py) using the `Label` as parent.

Comment: Ok...I get it now! Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score -2):

sorry but this is a bit too big to put in a comment and isn't a complete answer

I don't think you should need `ImageTk.` try running this: (I cant as I don't know what you want it to look like and I don't have those files on my pc)

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *  
root = Tk() 

# Creating photoimage objects to use in the buttons
home_button_image = PhotoImage(file = r"E:/Kiara Project/Screens/home_button.png")
note_button_image = PhotoImage(file = r"E:/Kiara Project/Screens/note_button.png")
about_button_image = PhotoImage(file = r"E:/Kiara Project/Screens/about_button.png")
menu_home_activated_image = PhotoImage(file = r"E:/Kiara Project/Screens/menu_home_activated.png")

# Making the buttons
home_button = Button(root, image = home_button_image).pack(side = TOP)
note_button = Button(root, image = note_button_image).pack(side = TOP)
about_button = note_button = Button(root, image = about_button_image).pack(side = TOP)

# Screens
lable = lable(root, image = menu_home_activated_image)
label.pack

root.update()

mainloop()
```

I cant guarantee this will work but it cleans up the code a bit and this was a bit rushed so there may be some mistakes

Comment: I have already tried this before writing the code I have given in the question, it does not work. It results in the same output. Anyway, thanks for your response.

Comment: Do not create widgets and pack widgets on the same line. `home_button etc.` will all be `None`